# Oracle VPD column level security error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got an error at

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28110: policy function or package VPD1.COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE has error
```

Below are my procs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE column_sec_package
AS
  FUNCTION test_sec (
      owner   VARCHAR2,
      objname VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE body COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE
IS
FUNCTION TEST_SEC (
    OWNER   VARCHAR2,
    OBJNAME VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_SQL VARCHAR2 ( 2000 ) := '1=0';
BEGIN
  IF ( SYS_CONTEXT ( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' ) = 'VPD1' ) THEN
    v_SQL := NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN V_SQL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY ( object_schema => 'VPD1', object_name => 'employee',
  policy_name => 'VPD1_POLICY_COLUMN1', function_schema => 'VPD1',
  policy_function => 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE.TEST_SEC', sec_relevant_cols =>
  'salary' ) ;
END;
/
```

Comment: Alex provided you solution when you asked last time, did you tried that? We cannot see `END` to your package body.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE column_sec_package
AS
  FUNCTION test_sec (
      owner   VARCHAR2,
      objname VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE body COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE
IS
FUNCTION TEST_SEC (
    OWNER   VARCHAR2,
    OBJNAME VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_SQL VARCHAR2 ( 2000 ) := '1=0';
BEGIN
  IF ( SYS_CONTEXT ( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' ) = 'VPD1' ) THEN
    v_SQL := NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN V_SQL;
END;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY ( object_schema => 'VPD1', object_name => 'employee',
  policy_name => 'VPD1_POLICY_COLUMN1', function_schema => 'VPD1',
  policy_function => 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE.TEST_SEC', sec_relevant_cols =>
  'salary' ) ;
END;
/
```

Comment: same error sir pls help me

Comment: Join [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49224/oracle-vpd-column-level-security-error)